# Is it possible to use ESRI:54009 (World_Mollweid) proj with rasterIo?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, pyproj

In a python environment I try to project from EPSG:4326 to ESRI:54009 to compute surfaces.

The ESRI description doesn't seem to be recognise by rasterio lib :

```
from rasterio.crs import CRS

CRS.from_string('ESRI:54009')
```

And I get the following error

> CRSError: The WKT could not be parsed. OGR Error code 5

instead if I use pyproj :

```
from pyproj import CRS 

CRS.from_string('ESRI:54009')
```

returns

```
<Projected CRS: ESRI:54009>
Name: World_Mollweide
Axis Info [cartesian]:
- E[east]: Easting (metre)
- N[north]: Northing (metre)
Area of Use:
- name: World
- bounds: (-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0)
Coordinate Operation:
- name: World_Mollweide
- method: Mollweide
Datum: World Geodetic System 1984
- Ellipsoid: WGS 84
- Prime Meridian: Greenwich
```

Unfortunately the rasterio calculate_default_transform requires a rasterio CRS. Is there a way to use the World_Mollweid in this lib ? (as it's incompatible with gdal python binding, I cannot use a simple gdal.Warp)

Comment: what if you use `from_proj4("+proj=moll +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m  no_defs")`

Comment: I'd like not use proj4 any more it's really not pythonic and less readable than 'EPSG:XXXX"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the indication of this page to see rasterio crs compatibility: https://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/crs_compatibility.html#rasterio

```py
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

import rasterio
from rasterio.crs import CRS as RioCRS
from pyproj.crs import CRS
from pyproj.enums import WktVersion

proj_crs = CRS.from_string('ESRI:54009')
if LooseVersion(rasterio.__gdal_version__) < LooseVersion("3.0.0"):
    rio_crs = RioCRS.from_wkt(proj_crs.to_wkt(WktVersion.WKT1_GDAL))
else:
    rio_crs = RioCRS.from_wkt(proj_crs.to_wkt())
```

**EDIT:**  Will be supported in rasterio 1.1.7 [PR](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/pull/1998) with GDAL 3+.